# Ruby: How do you trigger something only when inherited by a non-abstract class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, inheritance

I have an abstract `Base` class. Let's call it `Animal::Base`.

```
module Animal
  class Base < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.abstract_class = true # so that Rails won't think this is in STI-mode
    ordered_tree
  end
end
```

`ordered_tree` just applies the [OrderedTree](https://github.com/ramontayag/ordered_tree) gem to the class that invokes the method:

```
belongs_to :parent_node, :class_name => name, ...
```

It gets the name of the class that it is applied to. However, `name` at this point is `Animal::Base`, but I want it to be whatever inherits the `Animal::Base` class instead:

```
class Dog < Animal::Base
end
```

In this case, I want the parent_node to refer to the `Dog` class (effectively applying `belongs_to :parent_node, :class_name => "Dog", ...`), not `Animal::Base`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have to put your ordered_tree call in the Dog class.  There is also the self.included method, but that runs everything within the scope of the parent class, though it passes in the child class as a parameter.  So, maybe you could do something like:

```
module Animal
  class Base < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.abstract_class = true
    def self.inherited(chld)
      chld.send('ordered_tree')
    end
  end
end
```

I haven't tried this myself and suspect you may run into the same problem (ordered_tree still running in context of Base) but it's worth a shot...

Comment: Great! Thanks. I ended up doing exactly what you placed, except I added `super` right below `chld.send(...)`. I got errors without it, I suppose because Rails does other stuff with `self.included` that was overwritten without `super`.